# cocos2d v3 Collision detection without the physical collision?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I haven't been able to wrap my mind around this yet.

Lets say I have a ball that bounces around a room with a bunch of moving targets in the center of said room.

I want the ball to collide with the walls to bounce. I also want the targets to collide with the walls and bounce.

But I want the ball to pass right through the targets but still register a collision and call it's delegate.

How can I do this? I have a feeling collision masks hold the answer but I haven't been able to get it to work yet.

Answer (score 0):

I GOT IT! And of course after 2 days of tinkering I figure it out only minutes after posting here.

```
-(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair ball:(CCNode *)nodeA wildcard:(CCNode *)nodeB{
    NSLog(@"collision happend");
    return NO;
}
```

returning NO on ccPhysicsCollisionBegin prevents them from interacting.